# Uploading and displaying images through API

Tags: mysql, json, image, api, image-uploading

On my site I use uploads.im (http://uploads.im/apidocs) to let the user upload an image, which I display on the same page. I let the user submit the image through this form.

```
<form method="POST" action="http://uploads.im/api?upload&resize_width=350" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
</form>
```

When I upload an image I get the following JSON back:

```
{
  "status_code": 200,
  "status_txt": "OK",
  "data": {
    "img_name": "FhXqn.jpg",
    "img_url": "http:\/\/sk.uploads.im\/FhXqn.jpg",
    "img_view": "http:\/\/uploads.im\/FhXqn.jpg",
    "img_width": "350",
    "img_height": 233,
    "img_attr": "width=\"350\" height=\"233\"",
    "img_size": "29.3 KB",
    "img_bytes": 30051,
    "thumb_url": "http:\/\/sk.uploads.im\/t\/FhXqn.jpg",
    "thumb_width": 360,
    "thumb_height": 240,
    "source": "base64 image string",
    "resized": "1",
    "delete_key": "2c8b42a2daa7436b"
  }
}
```

How can I get the image url from this JSON so I can store it in my MYSQL database? And how do I prevent the user from ever seeing this JSON and just go back to my site after the upload?

Comment: 1) Decode the JSON into an array. Then reference the file info and whatever else you need to store it. 2) Don't display it. You don't mention what language you're using on the server side.